# "Set aside the round" and "forfeit it" meaning?

Tags: word-meaning

It's from the movie The Big Lebowski.

2 men named Walter and Smoki are playing in a bowling league team. Both belong to a different team. Because of an argument , Walter pulled out a gun and aimed it in Smoki's face. Later , Smoki call The Dude( Walter's teamate) that he will submit this to the leage.

> SMOKEY ON MACHlNE:
>    Dude, this is Smokey.Look, l don't wanna be a hard-on about this,and I know it wasn't  your fault, but l just thought it was fair to tell you that Gilbert and l will be
>   submitting this to the league and asking them to **set aside the round**.I don't know,
>   maybe **forfeit it to us**.So, like l say, just thought, you know, fair warning.Tell Walter.

What does he mean when he says "Set aside the round" and "forfeit it to us". What does he want?

Answer (score 1):

S. wants the league to invalidate or nullify that round as if it had never taken place, or possibly, he says, to make S. the winner of it.  The *choice* would be between setting the round aside or forfeiting the round to S.

Answer (score 1):

Smokey thinks the bowling round (session of play) should be addressed by the league, because he finds it unfair that Walter pointed a gun at him during it. As you know, he's submitting a message to the bowling league. He's proposing to the league that they either disqualify the round and make it worth nothing (set aside), or even that The Dude's team should give up the win to Smokey (forfeit, or give up).